# getting headline and datepublished required and missing errror in blogger

Tags: blogger, structured-data

While I am using structured data testing tool to check the structured data of my blogger blog i am getting blogposting errors regarding date and headling.

datepublished error in this code

```
<abbr class='published updated' itemprop='datePublished' title='2015-07-06T07:12:00-07:00'>
```

and headline missing and required error in this code

```
<article class='post hentry' itemprop='blogPost' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
```

I have searched alot on google but did not find any solution so please help me in this error.

Answer (score 1):

Same happens to me, it seems to be a testing tool bug, review the [Article-specific usage guidelines and policies](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles). I can't recall the exact data but Google updated the structured data documentation earlier this year. Google didn't support Article type for rich snippets.

In the past you could optimize your site for the in-depth articles feature. To optimize the site Google recommended marking up Article type and recommended marking up the following properties (not necessarily required),

- headline
- alternativeHeadline
- image
- description
- datePublished
- articleBody

With the release of the new documentation, Article type is supported and the following properties are required, headline, image and datePublished.

Answer (score 0):

change `title` attribute to `content` attribute

```
<abbr class='published updated' itemprop='datePublished' title='2015-07-06T07:12:00-07:00'>

<abbr class='published updated' itemprop='datePublished' content='2015-07-06T07:12:00-07:00'>
```